# Auxiliary memory for merge sort?

Tags: mergesort

I did google to understand auxiliary memory and it states "Auxiliary memory holds programs and data for future use, and, because it is nonvolatile (like ROM), it is used to store inactive programs and to archive data."
Here the link for the article: https://www.britannica.com/technology/computer-memory/Auxiliary-memory

So, I just want to try to understand why is auxiliary memory needed for a textbook implementation of mergesort?

Answer (score 0):

The link is using the term "auxiliary memory" as a reference to external storage. The term "auxiliary memory" is also used to describe additional buffers in main memory. A standard implementation of merge sort uses a second array the same size as the original array to hold data as it merges back and forth between the two arrays. In this case the term "auxiliary memory" is being used to describe the additional buffer (the second array) in main memory.